# PayPal IPN does not work for outgoing transactions (send money)

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have a business account (BA) with IPN configured.  There are two cases:

1. Incoming transaction from anyone to BA, IPN works successfully
2. Outgoing transaction from BA to anyone, IPN does not work

I would like to configure IPN for the 2nd case, is it possible?

I need know in real time (on the fly) all transactions data sent to some endpoint to our server.

Comment: What do you mean by "work"? The IPNs never arrive? Or they are not handled correctly by your code? What's in the IPN History for these? You really need to provide more clarity in order for this question to be answerable.

Comment: @BenM
Yes, "The IPNs never arrive" for outcoming transactions.

IPN History contains only incoming transactions.

Comment: @BenM
At same time PayPal activity history contains all transactions incoming and outcoming, status of all transactions 'Completed', and IPN history contain only incoming transaction

Comment: So this issue is actually related to PayPal, not your own code?

Comment: @BenM
Server endpoint which catch PayPal IPN notifications at current time only store _POST data to log file without any conditions before . And PP incoming transactions data stored, PP outcoming transactions data not stored to log file.

ps . Log file only during development, before production logging will be removed

Answer (score 0):

Instant Payment Notification (IPN) notifies of payments received.

The service does not notify of payments sent.

Comment: Preston PHX, does PayPal have any way to catch outcoming transaction data on fly(in real time) ?

Comment: Just the response of whatever API you are using to send a transaction, for example a Payouts API response